# Initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal ' protection level

Tags: swift

I have a struct defined in Swift with  public properties

```
public struct MyStruct {
   
    public let prop1: String
    public let prop2: String
}
```

In my code, I try to initialize the struct by doing

> MyStruct(prop1: "abc", prop2: "def")

But I get complier error saying 'MyStruct initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal protection' level.

The struct and member are in public protection level. So I don't understand what is 'internal' protection level.

Comment: Weird. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: ` all public struct need a public init` @Sweeper this is not the case in swift 5.1 ?

Comment: @jawadAli In this case an initialiser should be automatically generated, but according to OP, it's not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First there are five different protection levels: `private`, `fileprivate`, `internal`, `public` and `open`.

Any property, func or **initializer** you declare without a protection level keyword will automatically be declared as `internal`.

Internal means, that your property, method or initializer is accessible everywhere **within the same module**.

> It seems like you are trying to create a new struct out of another module. **Best solution would probably be to create your own `init` instead of the automatically generated one and declare it also as public.**

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This doesn't answer what n179911 is talking about.
The question can be decrypted by: "Why in case of struct synthesised initialiser this one is still set as internal to the module while the struct is declared as public and also its properties.
It's completely inconvenient to have to create initialisers for structs since one of their main characteristics is initialiser synthesising.

Answer (score 0):

`struct` have the default member wise initialiser. Means if you don't provide any `init` for struct then compiler automatically synthesise that for you. The default synthesised `init` would be created like

```
init(member: Type, ...) { 
   /// Initialisation here.
}
```

So your struct with the automatically synthesised initialiser would look like ---

```
public struct MyStruct {
   
    public let prop1: String
    public let prop2: String

    /// Auto generated init will be like 
    init(prop1: String, prop2: String) {
        self.prop1 = prop1
        self.prop2 = prop2
    }
}
```

As you can see the property type is `public` but the initialiser type is `internal` so that is causing this issue. You can create initialiser that will fix it.

Answer (score -1):

you don't have to define the struct's properties as public,

just the initializer (**public init**) like this:

```
public struct MyStruct {

   let prop1: String
   let prop2: String

   public init(prop1: String, prop2: String){
       self.prop1 = prop1
       self.prop2 = prop2
   }

}
```